cubic twists of Mordell curve and their rank
Let $a$ be a non-zero integer. Consider the elliptic curve $E_a/\mathbb{Q}$ given by the equation
$$
E_a: y^2 = x^3 + a.
$$
For a cube-free integer $D$, define the elliptic curves $E_{aD^2}/\mathbb{Q}$ and $E_{aD^4}/\mathbb{Q}$. These are cubic twists of the original elliptic curve.
I would like to know if there are any results on how often exactly one of $E_a$, $E_{aD^2}$ or $E_{aD^4}$ has positive rank and the other two have rank 0. [This will of course depend on the choice of $a$ and $D$, but for my purpose it will be enough to know the answer for a fixed value of $a$ and as $D$ varies.]
The flip question is say we fix a cube-free integer $D$. Should there always exist an integer $a$ such that exactly one of $E_a$, $E_{aD^2}$ or $E_{aD^4}$ has positive rank and the other two have rank 0? [I tried this for all cube-free integers $1< D\le 100$. For $D=71,83$ I have not been able to find such an $a$ (yet) but this might be due to my impatience.]

You can refer to my paper, M. Ulas, "A Note on Higher Twists of Elliptic Curves," Glasg. Math. J. 52 (2010), no. 2, 371–381, where the question of the existence of simultaneous cubic/sextic twists of elliptic curves with $j=0$ with positive ranks is considered.

@MaciejUlas From what I understand, you prove that starting with two elliptic curves $y^2 = x^3 + a$ and $y^2 = x^3 + b$, there exist (many) $D$ such that $y^2 = x^3 + aD^2$ and $y^2 = x^3 + bD^2$ are both of positive rank.
However, I want to start with $y^2 = x^3 + a$ and $y^2 = x^3 + aD^2$. Suppose I start with $a$ such that $y^2 = x^3 + a$ has rank 0. Then as $D$ varies, your theorem says that there are many $D$'s for which both $y^2 = x^3 + aD^2$ and $y^2 = x^3 + aD^4$ have positive rank. But I would like exactly one to be of positive rank.
But maybe I misunderstood something.

Yes, you are right. I just wanted to mention that the related question, where the three mentioned curves have positive ranks, should be relatively easy to answer using the method from my paper.
